# how to receive custom metadata in pendo?

Tags: pendo

I'm trying to receive custom metadata in pendo,

I added in 'Data Mappings' in the account section  - custom metadata 'data' in type 'Text',

and I am sending it in the correct form in the pendoInitialize request.

but I don't know where I can see it in the Pendo UI website.

I'ver searched all over their website and the Dr. google but nothing came to light.

I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pendo's custom metadata has errors and a lot of lag time,

currently what can be used is the 'user' section for custom metadata,
and again it has a lot of lag time so the changes will be seen only after 1-3 hours.

it has to be actively put in the 'Data mapping' in the 'user' section as the same exact field name, with a specific type, but it will be shown in 1-3 hours.